# Mostrar imagem após fechar o aplicativo e abrir novament

Tags: javascript, android, apache-cordova, ionic

Tenho esse código, e com ele eu consigo tirar uma foto e exibir a foto no lugar da imagem da câmera logo após fechar a câmera. Mas como fazer última imagem tirada na câmera aparecer na hora que abrir o aplicativo?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

    <!-- Descomente esse código para ativar o service worker
    <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
          .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
          .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
      }
    </script>-->

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    </head>
   <body ng-app="starter">

        <ion-pane>

          <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">

            <!-- Título que está acima da imagem -->
            <h1 class="title col text-center">Câmera</h1>

          </ion-header-bar>

            <ion-content ng-controller="MainCtrl">  

             <img ng-src="{{srcImage || 'img/dummy.jpg'}}" id="srcImage" width="350 " height="350" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;"/><br/>              
             <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="takeImage() ">Tirar uma foto</button><br/>

           </ion-content>

        </ion-pane>
      </body>
    </html>
```

**app.js**

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });


})

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaCamera) {
    $scope.takeImage = function() {
        var options = {
            quality: 100,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
            allowEdit: true,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            targetWidth: 350,
            targetHeight: 350,
            popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
            correctOrientation: true
        };

        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
            $scope.srcImage = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        }, function(err) {
            // error
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: Bom o código em si eu teria que criar mas a lógica é simples. 1º você deve salvar a ultima imagem em algum db (sqlite ou localStorage). 2º ao abrir a tela, sua app verifica se esse parametro existe (Ex: localStorage.lastImage.length > 0), caso exista ele alimenta o controller.

Comment: A foto está sendo salva na memória do aparelho

Comment: o problema é que a memória pode ser despejada ou reutilizada dependendo do processo que está sendo usado. no Android, ao sair ele congela a aplicação deixando essa na memória mas, se a pessoa realmente fechar a aplicação, vc perde aquilo. por isso é interessante salvar nem que sejam em um txt...

Comment: Não tenho ideia de como fazer isso.